# Rm behavior in linux

Tags: linux, shell, rm

If I'm in a directory like:

```
/home/usr_name/Documents/test
```

And, accidentally, I launch:

```
rm .*
```

What happens?
I thought it would remove all the files that contained a dot.. but I definitely was wrong!

Comment: You can for example do `ls *.` to see what it is matching.

Comment: ls: cannot access *.: No such file or directory

Comment: Then it is not matching anything :)

Comment: uhm.. I'm sure that something has been deleted.. maybe command was "rm .*"

Comment: I hope it was not `rm .*` because this one matches way more things.

Comment: damn... looking in history yes, is "rm .*".. in this case what happens?

Comment: It may have deleted any files inside hidden dirs (those that have name starting with `.`), current dir (it is `.`) and dir above current (it is `..`). So if you are in `/home/me`, you may have deleted files in `/home`, `/home/me` and `/home/me/.dir`

Comment: See my answer. But in general, if you do `rm (something)` and then immediately follow it with `ls (something)` the `ls` is going to report no matching files, because you already deleted them.

Answer (score 2):

It matches `.*` according to the globbing rules of your shell. For the shells I'm familiar with (bash, tcsh) it will match all files *beginning* with a dot. Use `*.*` for all files *containing* a dot or `*.` for all files *ending* with a dot.

In general, `*` matches any sequence of characters; however, it will not usually match a leading dot (i.e. `*` by itself won't match filenames beginning with a dot, but `.*` will).

Comment: please take a look at edit, command was rm .*

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When using `rm` and not sure about using wild characters `*`, always do a

```
ls .*
```

whatever is the output, that is what `rm` is going to work on when you do a `rm .*`

Comment: ls: cannot access *.: No such file or directory

Comment: then `rm` won't do anything here. And moreover it means file ending with a `.` in its name. Do you have any such files in your directory ? Add a `ls -al` output in your question.

Comment: please take a look at edit, command was rm .*

Comment: It deleted everything with a `.` in begining of its name !